# instanceOf in a Controller class ok? (Cannot edit any other class)

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

The project has 4 classes. A Person, an Employee that extends Person and an Academic that extends Employee.
I also have a Store, which is a user-made alternative to an Array. One of the functions of Store is ‘elementAt()’, which returns to us an object in Store.

The problem I have is that elementAt() always returns as type Person. This is a huge problem because, in my Controller class, before I let the user perform an action only applicable to an Academic I NEED to check whether the user has actually chosen an employee or not.

```
public Person elementAt(int index)
{
// Returns element at position index
return list[index];
}
```

There is one big problem; according to the project specification I cannot alter the Person, Employee, Academic or Store class any further. Meaning, I have to determine the type of the Store index somewhere, somehow within my controller class.

I wanted to run this by people with more experience so thank you for having a look.

Comment: I think it is a wrong way to hardcode this and implicitly create permissions (permissions not in a sense of permitting the subject to do sth, but in the sense of things being done to an object). Wether something can be done by or done to an object should be determined by permissions. Imho, a method interceptor checking rules for the object to process would be a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instanceof seems to me the only option you have; and I don't think that its evil to use it in this case. But you are right, it is not the nicest thing in thinking in objects ;o)

At least you might encapsulate that like

```
public boolean isAcademic(Person p) {
    return p instanceof Academic;
}
```

to concentrate the "code smell" in one position, and make it easier to later refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got it right, but if you just want to check the returned object type, do this:

```
Person person = store.elementAt(0);
if (person instanceof Academic) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I have used this in my program but I have read, on Stack Overflow an elsewhere, that using 'instanceof' is frowned upon. I was just fishing for any potential alternatives but thanks for offering some help!

Comment: so how come the accepted answer suggests the exact same thing? hahaha